# Azure CLI Create AD App with AllowImplicit

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

Is there any way that I can create or modify an AzureAD App to allow the OAuth 2.0 Implicit flow via the Azure CLI 2.0?

I'm able to create app registrations without issue using [az ad app create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like the Azure CLI 2.0 exposes the `OAuth2AllowImplicitFlow` property to be set, however the [Azure Active Directory PowerShell 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/New-AzureADApplication?view=azureadps-2.0) does expose this property:

> `-Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow`
>
> Specifies whether this web application can request OAuth2.0 implicit
> flow tokens. The default is false.
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Position: Named
>
> Default value:    None
>
> Accept pipeline input:    False
>
> Accept wildcard characters:   False

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, the answer is, not really. I'd need to switch all of the other provisioning that I have working just fine to use PowerShell for this one step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLI to call Graph API to do achieve that. This method needs to create `service principal` in your AAD Tenant, and assign `Company Admin role` to it.

**Get an authentication token**

```
curl -X "POST" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token" \
-H "Cookie: flight-uxoptin=true; stsservicecookie=ests; x-ms-gateway-slice=productionb; stsservicecookie=ests" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--data-urlencode "client_id=$APPID" \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=client_credentials" \
--data-urlencode "client_secret=$PASSWORD" \
--data-urlencode "resource=https://graph.windows.net/"
```

**Set the AAD applicaiton Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow to be true:**

```
curl -X "PATCH" "https://graph.windows.net/$TENANTID/applications/$ObjectId?api-version=1.6" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESSTOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d $'{"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow":true}'
```

After few seconds, Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow of your application has been set to be true.

Additional, as [@Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396977/shawn-tabrizi) said that Azure CLI doesn't have this cmdlet to set AAD Application,but Azure Powershell have. However Azure CLI is an important tool for Linux platform to use Azure. I think we can post this feature feedback in [this Page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues). Azure Team will review it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Creative, but not really a solution for my problem due to the authentication scheme you're targeting there. I never want to handle credentials in my own code as a matter of practice, hence using CLI and device login. 
Thanks for the link to the github project, I've raised an issue/feature request :)

Comment: @GavinB My pleasure ：-）