# How to set user assignment required to true by azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-cli

Found `-AppRoleAssignmentRequired` `$false` for **powershell** module but looking for **azure-cli** to set user assignment required to `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure CLI doesn't support this feature currently. You can give your feedback in [this Page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues).

Additional, if you must need to use Azure CLI to approach , I suggest you can use AAD Graph API via CLI. There is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394544/azure-cli-create-ad-app-with-allowimplicit/49398652#49398652) in SO. You can refer to my answer to achieve that.

Hope this helps!